# Which are minimum resources to deploy a Elasticsearch cluster? 1 master - 2 nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have deployed a cluster of ElasticSearch in 4 nodes of Centos 7, but the sataus os cluster is red, I attached the ERROR bellow:

```
Error: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed
at respond (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:111:161556)
at checkRespForFailure (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:111:160796)
at http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:105:285566
at processQueue (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:132456)
at http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:133349
at Scope.$digest (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:144239)
at Scope.$apply (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:147018)
at done (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:100026)
at completeRequest (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:104697)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (http://172.18.13.66:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:105435
```

I have been read in other post that this error means I do not have sufficient disk available or suficient RAM available. Which are the minimum resources to solve this?

Comment: What’s your box specs?

Comment: Actually are sort 10GB of Hard disk and 4GB of RAM and 2 cores, but i do this only for testing. But now i wnat know how much i need to deploy the cluster,

Comment: In general should be okay to run elastic. Do you have index already? What’s the size is? Could you share your jvm.options from Elasticsearch configs?

Comment: I let you my jvm.options [here](https://pastebin.com/v426BhgP) but I didn´t modify this file.And RAM is 2GB sorry for the mistake.